# How to find the mapping class groups of the tori $T^3$ and $T^4$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to find any reference for the mapping class groups of the three and four-dimensional tori $T^3$ and $T^4$.

Here "mapping class group" means the isotopy classes of diffeomorphisms.

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody knows the mapping class group of $T^4$. I don't know a reference off the top of my head, but the mapping class group of $T^3$ is $GL_3 \Bbb Z$. This is mostly elementary, except in the end you need to appeal to the theorem of Cerf that $\text{Diff}(D^3, S^2)$ is connected (this being the group of diffeomorphisms that fix the boundary pointwise).

Comment: @MikeMiller Is there a reference to show the mapping class group of $T^3$ is $GL(3,Z)$?

Comment: A theorem of Waldhausen states that if $M$ is a Haken manifold, then $\text{Out}(\pi_1 M) \cong MCG(M)$.  This includes $M = T^3$ as a special case. You can find a proof in Chapter 13 of Hempel's book on 3-manifolds.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks.